# Swift get the day of the month from a date reliably

Tags: swift, date, time, timezone

I am looking into a bug in my birthday app. The member `.day` of `Date` returns the wrong day but curiously only in the timezone UTC-4. `.year` and `.month` are totally fine too. Are there any other ways to get the day of the month from a date reliably in any given timezone?

```
let birthday = Date().midnightUTC() // 2002-01-12 00:00:00 +0000

func upcomingBirthday() -> Date {
        var dc = DateComponents()
        dc.calendar = .current
        dc.year = Date().year
        dc.month = birthday.month
        dc.day = birthday.day
        
        print("Date Day: \(birthday.day)") // 10

        let today = Date().midnightUTCDate()

        if dc.date! == today {
            return today
        } else if dc.date!.midnightUTCDate().isEarlierThan(today) {
            dc.year! += 1
            return dc.date!            
        } else {
            return  dc.date!.midnightUTCDate()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In general, you should be trying to  compare your dates within the same timezone, so maybe, converting both `Date`s to UTC, for example

Comment: Don't store it as date. Store it as date components

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't think that's the correct approach. The guy can be anywhere in the world when it is his birthday regardless where he/she were born

Comment: Don't use UTC. Use the device timezone.

Comment: @LeoDabus But there's your problem, you've got one date in UTC and one date in local time zone - this allows for the UTC day to be before or after the local date, so you need to start with a common baseline

Comment: I've been mucking around with this and as near as I can tell, `Date` (or `NSDate`) doesn't have an associated time zone, so the problem isn't with `Date` (and it's not required to try and convert it to a given time zone), but the problem seems to be with how the `day`, `month` and `year` values are been calculated, but since they seem to be extensions, it's not possible to fully ascertain what the core problem might be.  From this exploration, I'd agree with Leo, use `DateComponents` more directly - the timezone should be left for presentions

Comment: @MadProgrammer Correct, the problem is with the calculation `day` and not the UTC conversion. I only do that, because I need to know wether the stored birthday (which could be in any time zone), is today in the local time zone. While I could calculate the `day` myself, using `DateComponents` directly to store the birthday seems to be the easier solution.